# Does the f_oneway test for regression from SciPy take the y values and the fitted y values as arguments?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I did a nonlinear regression using `curve_fit` and wanted an F test on this regression. I wanted to use `f_oneway` test for regression but I am not sure what to enter into the function. I entered two numpy arrays, `y` (the actual data for the dependent variable) and `yfit` the data predicted by the regression equation I received using `curve_fit`. I am not sure if this will give me an F test for the "Overall Significance" of the independent variables. I do not understand what the Scipy official site is saying about this.

I ran the following code:

```
    import scipy.stats as stats 
    h = stats.f_oneway(y,yfit)
    print(h)
```

And received the following output:

> ```
> F_onewayResult(statistic=1.33717160489312e-19, pvalue=1.0)
> ```

However, I am not sure that I did the right thing by entering the `y` and `yfit` into the `f_oneway` function, to get an F test for overall significance.